# Generate network interfaces config using ansible/jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to generate unique network interface configurations for multiple devices using jinja2 and ansible but it keeps joining the interfaces for each of the items variable.

Expected output for each file.

First file for host `st1-gheb-gsoc-sw1`:

```
hostname st1-gheb-gsoc-sw1  
!  
interface Vlan217  
desc Mgmt-gateway  
ip address 10.179.117.209 255.255.255.0  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1  
description ACL_Panel_1  
switchport mode access  
switch access vlan 210  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2  
description GSOC Devices  
switchport mode access  
switch access vlan 210  
!  
!
```

Second file for host `st1-293-gsoc-sw1`:

```
hostname st1-293-gsoc-sw1
  
!  
interface Vlan217  
desc Mgmt-gateway  
ip address 10.179.117.200 255.255.255.0  
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1  
description ADC-1  
switchport mode access  
switch access vlan 210  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1  
description ACL_Panel_1  
switchport mode access  
switch access vlan 210  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2  
description ADC-2  
switchport mode access  
switch access vlan 210  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3  
description ICU-1  
switchport mode access  
switch access vlan 216  
!
```

jinja2 code tried so far:

```
!
!
hostname {{ item.hostname }}

!
interface Vlan217
desc Mgmt-gateway
ip address {{ item.mgmt_ip }} 255.255.255.0
!
{% for i in ios_switches %}
{% for j in i['items'] %}
interface {{ j.name }}
description {{ j.desc }}
switchport mode access
switch access vlan {{ j.vlan_id }}
!
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

yaml data file:

```yaml
---
ios_switches:
  - hostname: st1-gheb-gsoc-sw1
    mgmt_ip: 10.179.117.209
    items:
      - name: GigabitEthernet1/0/1
        vlan_id: 210
        desc: ACL_Panel_1
      - name: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
        vlan_id: 210
        desc: GSOC Devices
  - hostname: st1-293-gsoc-sw1
    mgmt_ip: 10.179.117.200
    items:
      - name: GigabitEthernet1/0/1
        vlan_id: 210
        desc: ADC-1
      - name: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
        vlan_id: 210
        desc: ADC-2
      - name: GigabitEthernet1/0/3
        vlan_id: 216
        desc: ICU-1
```

Comment: I infer you are calling your jinja2 file in a loop over ` ios_switches` in an `ansble.builtin.template` task. (If I'm wrong please read [mre] and then [edit] your quetion). Your template is then just wrong. Remove the two imbricated `for` loops in the jinja2 template and replace with a single one => `{% for j in item.items %}`